# How to avoid 'null' when use scalatest with before/after?

Tags: scala, null, scalatest

From this [article about spark testing](http://mkuthan.github.io/blog/2015/03/01/spark-unit-testing/), there is some sample code:

```
class SparkExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfter {

  private val master = "local[2]"
  private val appName = "example-spark"

  private var sc: SparkContext = _

  before {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster(master)
      .setAppName(appName)

    sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  }

  after {
    if (sc != null) {
      sc.stop()
    }
  }
  (...)
```

It works, but there is a nullable varaible `sc`. It's reasonable here but I still want to avoid it.

I tried to use:

```
private var sc: Option[SparkContext] = None

  before {
    sc = Some(new SparkContext(conf))
  }

  after {
    sc.foreach(_.stop())
  }
  (...)
```

But the problem is, I have to use `sc` as `Option[SparkContext]` in the test which is not convenient as the plain one `SparkContext`

Is there way to keep the test working, but we can use `val sc: SparkContext`?

(I know it's possible in specs2, but not sure how to do it in scalatest, and we have to use scalatest now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop using the `before` and just use a `lazy val` instead, so the context is initialized when the first test calls it:

```
class SparkExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with BeforeAndAfter {

  private val master = "local[2]"
  private val appName = "example-spark"

  private lazy val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster(master)
    .setAppName(appName)
  private lazy val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  after {
    sc.stop()
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

So I've run into something similar before and we ended up with a trait pattern like below:

```
trait SparkAddOn {

  val conf:SparkConf

  def withSpark(f: SparkContext => Unit) ={
    val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    try{
      f(sc)
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
    }
  }
}
```

So then in your test you just use 'withSpark':

```
class SparkExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with SparkAddOn {

  private val master = "local[2]"
  private val appName = "example-spark"

  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster(master)
    .setAppName(appName)

  "test" should "do something" in withSpark { sc =>

  }
}
```

And I'll just conclude with I much prefer Specs2 to Scalatest, the design is drastically different and for the better, sorry you can't switch.

Comment: But there may be multiple tests, and the `sc` will be initialised only once if it's not inside the `before`

Comment: @Freewind I updated my solution, give it a try and let me know if it works for you

Comment: We ended up with the same solution :)